# Partial sum using telescopic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

The summation of $(n^2+1)\cdot n!$ using to $N$ using telescopic series.

**Question**: Find a closed expression in $n$ for:
\begin{gather}
\text{Let } u_n = (n^2+1)\cdot n! \\
\sum_{n=1}^{N}u_n = \sum_{n=1}^{N}(n^2+1)\cdot n!\\
\end{gather}

**My Attempt**
I tried to split $(n^2+1)\cdot n!$ into two different terms that would telescope.

First try
\begin{gather}
(n^2+1)\cdot n! = ((n+1)^2-2n)\cdot n! \\
= (n+1)\cdot (n+1)! - 2n\cdot n!\\
\sum_{n=1}^{N}(n+1)\cdot (n+1)! - 2n\cdot n!\\
(2)\cdot(2)! - 2(1)\cdot(1)!\\
(3)\cdot(3)! - 2(2)\cdot(2)! \\
\vdots \\
(n+1)\cdot (n+1)! - 2(n)\cdot (n)!\\
\end{gather}
The $2$ on the second term is quite annoying and needless to say it does not work.

Second try
\begin{gather}
(n^2+1)\cdot n! = ((n+1)^2-2n)\cdot n! \\
= (n+1)\cdot (n+1)! - 2n\cdot n!  =  (n+1)\cdot(n+1)! -2[(n+1)! - (n)!]\\
\end{gather}
Didn't work.

Try #3

\begin{gather}
(n+1)\cdot(n+1)! -2[(n+1)! - (n)!] = (n+1)!\cdot(n-1)+2n!\\
\end{gather}
This one didn't help at all.

Could anyone please suggest a hint to arrive at the right telescoping expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that $$(n^2+1)\cdot n! = n\cdot(n+1)! - (n-1)\cdot n!.$$
Thus $$\sum_{n=1}^Nu_n=(N\cdot(N+1)!-(N-1)\cdot N!) + ((N-1)\cdot N! - (N-2)\cdot (N-1)!) +\\+ \cdots + (1\cdot2!-0\cdot1!) = N\cdot(N+1)!.$$

Comment: Thanks for that. Neat split of the expression. How did you think of that though?

Comment: A lot of the time with these telescoping functions you need to guess the right way to telescope it, but the guesses are not random.  Here for instance, since $n!$ is already recursive, I started with $f(n+1)(n+1)! - f(n)n!$ since that handles the $n!$ factor.  Then it is pretty clear that $f(n) = n-1$ conveniently works!

Comment: When you $n!$ is recursive, what exactly do you mean? How does it point to itself?

Comment: When telescoping we want to find a function $g(n)$ such that the nth term of our sum is equal to $g(n+1) - g(n)$.  When I said $n!$ is recursive I was referring to the definition $n! = n\cdot (n-1)!$.  In other words we can try $g(n) = f(n)\cdot n!$ and $g(n+1) = f(n+1)\cdot (n+1)! = f(n+1)\cdot(n+1)\cdot n!$ so we can now divide out by $n!$ to get $f(n+1)\cdot(n+1)-f(n) = n^2+1$, yielding the solution $f(n) = n-1$.

Comment: Yes that makes so much sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
let $b_n := n[(n+1)!]$ and compute $b_n - b_{n-1}$.

Comment: How do you approach telescopic series in general? If its something that can  undergo partial fractional decomposition, then I see the method, but for other cases how do you approach the question?